# Solving inequality involving floor function

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have this inequality (over real numbers) :
$$x^2-2x\le \frac{\sqrt{1-\lfloor x\rfloor^2}}{\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor}$$

How we can solve it using both of algebraic and geometric methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $x$ cannnot be integer, otherwise the denominator of the RHS would be $0$.

So $x$ is not integer, which gives $\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor -x \rfloor=-1$

Also $\lfloor x \rfloor\in\{-1,0,1\}$ since it must be integer and $1-\lfloor x\rfloor^2>0$ which is equivalent to $\lfloor x\rfloor^2<1$.

Then you solve on each interval $-1<x<0$, $0<x<1$, and $1<x<2$

EDIT: For a geometric solution, I would plot $x^2-2x$ and I would observe that the RHS is either $0$ or $-1$.

Comment: Thank you , But what about geometric solution ?

Comment: I added my thoughts about what would be a "geometric" solution

Comment: Okay , I gave $1<x<2$ . Am I right ?

Comment: It looks correct. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+of+y%3Dx%5E2-2x+and+y%3Dsqrt(1-floor(x)%5E2)%2F(floor(x)%2Bfloor(-x))++for+x%3D-1.5+to2.5) might give you an idea about "geometric method"

Comment: The OP asked for real numbers. Besides, I've never seen $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ on complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

RHS is defined only for $-2< x<2$ and $x\ne0$..

If $-1<x<0$ or $0<x<1$, then RHS is $\frac{1}{-1}=-1$. Solve $x^2-2x+1\le0$ and only keep solutions in the initial interval.

If $1\le |x|<2$, RHS is $0$, solve $x^2-2x\le 0$ and only keep solutions in intervals $\left]-2,-1\right]$ and $\left[1,2\right[$.

Remember, when you encounter something like $\lfloor x\rfloor$ or $\left|x\right|$, try first to give it a value by making hypothesis on the positions of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}x= \lfloor x\rfloor+\{x\}\\-x= \lfloor -x\rfloor+1-\{x\}\end{cases}\Rightarrow\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor -x\rfloor=-1$$

$$\sqrt{1-\lfloor x\rfloor^2}=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } -1\le x\lt0\\1\text{ if }  0\le x\lt1\\0 \text{ if } 1\le x\lt2\end{cases}$$ Hence
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\lfloor x\rfloor^2}}{\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor -x\rfloor}=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } -1\le x\lt0\\-1\text{ if }  0\le x\lt1\\0 \text{ if } 1\le x\lt2\end{cases}$$

It follows that if $f(x)=x^2-2x$ then since $$f((-1,0))=(0,3)\\f([0,1))=[-1,0]\\f([1,2))=[-1,0)$$ the solution is $$1\le x\lt 2$$

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything more than Momo's answer. But since you asked for a geometric solution as well, this may also help:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank You a lot , Can You say how to plotted this graph ?

Comment: @S.H.W : I usually use [online Wolfram Mathematica](https://mathematica.wolframcloud.com/app)

Comment: `Plot[{Sqrt[1-Floor[x]^2]/(Floor[x]+Floor[-x]),x^2-2x}, {x,-1.5,2.5}, PlotLegends->"Expressions"]`

Comment: Okay , Thank you again.